# WPF GridView export to CSV?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView` which is having `GridView` as its View.

See the sample code below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="DataGridCheckBox">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}},Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="EmployeesGridView">
            <GridViewColumn Header="IsEligible">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Employee.Name}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Age">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I export this data to `CSV` file. I am not getting any property by which I can get Rows present in `GridView`.

How can I do this. Please suggest.

Comment: Doesn't Employees represent the items in the ListView? You want to export all Employees or just selected ones?

Comment: I want selected one. For all I can use DataContext.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `SelectedPerson` property in your `ViewModel` and bind `ListView.SelectedItem` to this property.